# How to Organize and Deploy Cloud Function Project with Shared Library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

This is what I'm currently doing.  It's undesirable because it replicates identical lib/ folder with shared functions:

```
/project/
└── /cloudfunctions/
    ├── /functionA/
    │   ├── main.py
    │   └── /lib/
    └── /functionB/
        ├── main.py
        └── /lib/
```

How do I organize or deploy functions so that the project structure can be more like this?

```
/project/
└── /cloudfunctions/
    ├── /functionA/
    │   └── main.py
    ├── /functionB/
    │   └── main.py
    └── /lib/
```

To clarify more, I'm wondering how there isn't an `--include-dependencies` flag for `gcloud functions deploy` and I'm wondering what the best practice is to include a shared library like in the second folder structure.

For now this is my janky hack in `deploy.sh`

```
rm -rf lib
cp -r ../lib ./lib
gcloud functions deploy...
```

Comment: Is this a deployment question or a development question?

Comment: Deployment: To Cloud Functions your library is not shared. Your library is a dependency that you must provide.

Comment: Development: Organize your code any way your want. When you are ready to deploy copy the required files into the structure that Cloud Functions requires for deployment.

Comment: Option C: use Cloud Run! When you are building your container do what you want with your source/directory in the Dockerfile.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm not sure what best practices are.  I don't see an option in the `gcloud functions deploy` command to package additional libraries.  This seems like it would be a common condition to have different functions with a shared library.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere avoiding cloudrun for now as it requires even more overhead in managing and deploying images

Comment: I think your issue is that you are approaching Cloud Functions as a "program". It is not, it is a function, which is a subset of a program. Functions are a micro-task, that should be as small as practical. To be a good Cloud Functions developer, consider rethinking your approach. As far as best practices, I don't really follow any. If I need to do something my preferred way, I just create my own tools. However, Cloud Run is much easier to develop for than Cloud Functions (opinions vary). Consider both for your deployments.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO, Dockerfile overhead VS ` deploy.sh`  overhead. It's an opinion as @Johnhanley said, and I'm Cloud Run fan, my opinion is biased! Think about maintainability, portability to GKE (why not?) concurrency processing,... Anyway, if your 2 functions use the same lib, they maybe (but it's not sure) can belong to the same microservice and you could deploy both in the same container. Consider your use case and not the 1 shot overhead ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have multiple functions in a single directory. A common structure would be as follows:

```
.
├── common
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Where `main.py` contains both functions:

```
from common import module1, module2

def cloudfunction1(request):
    ...

def cloudfunction2(request):
    ...
```

And you deploy those functions either directly by name:

```
$ gcloud beta functions deploy cloudfunction1 --runtime python37 --trigger-http
$ gcloud beta functions deploy cloudfunction2 --runtime python37 --trigger-http
```

Or by entrypoint:

```
$ gcloud beta functions deploy foo --runtime python37 --entry-point cloudfunction1 --trigger-http
$ gcloud beta functions deploy bar --runtime python37 --entry-point cloudfunction2 --trigger-http
```

Comment: is there a way I can test more than one function locally on same time?

Comment: Yes! See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python/tree/master/examples/skaffold

Comment: And if I have 100+ cloud functions, and each functions has several helpers functions, all this functions must be in one main.py? And when I deploy one function, I must deploy whole code?

Comment: Hey @stahh ! Did you ever find a good solution for this problem? I feel the same way. Once my project starts scaling, having a hundred cloud functions in one file becomes more difficult to debug.

Comment: @GiggleGrass not that way. I decided to use https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies